# AS3 - Shares Slider System

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been tearing my hair out with this problem for quite some time now, basically I have a created a profit distribution system which includes the functionality to allow a number of partners to have their shares set on a slider from 0-100.

Where I am having trouble is preventing the slider from setting an unrealistic value i.e. in the case that one Partner has 100% of the shares set. At the moment I am testing with the following code in the Partner class slider event listener:

```
        // check we don't use more responsibility shares than available
        if(rs_sldr.value < availableShares + rs_sldr.value) {

            // update shares value if valid
            RSShares = rs_sldr.value;
        }
```

The availableShares value is being taken from a general Partners class and is updated each time a partner slider is adjusted by adding all of the Partner shares values together and deducting from the total available shares (100).

I'm adding the slider value in the if statement to create the right scale as if I use just the available shares value the slider can set no more than fifty for the first partner as at 50 there are only 50 shares left and the if statement is triggered. I'm sure there's a more logical way to do this!!!

Anyway here is my code, here's hoping someone can rescue me from the misery this is causing me. Many thanks.

General Partners class:

```
package com.example.profitdistributiondiagram {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.example.profitdistributiondiagram.events.PartnerEvent;
import flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter;
import flash.globalization.LocaleID;

public class Partners extends MovieClip {

    public var TPGrossPerc:Number = 0;
    public var TPGrossAmount:Number = 0;

    public var RSShareValue:Number = 0;
    public var RSGrossShareAmount:Number = 0;
    public var RSGrossAmount:Number = 0;
    public var RSNetAmount:Number = 0;

    public var PPGrossPoints:Number = 0;
    public var PPGrossAmount:Number = 0;

    public var DGrossPerc:Number = 0;
    public var DGrossAmount:Number = 0;

    public var partners = new Array();
    public var FDAmount:Number = 0;
    public var totalInputRS:Number = 0;
    public var totalInputPP:Number = 0;
    public var totalInputD:Number = 0;      

    public var availableShares:Number = 100;

    private var cf:CurrencyFormatter;

    public function Partners() {

        cf = new CurrencyFormatter( "en-UK" );
        cf.setCurrency("EUR", "€");
        cf.fractionalDigits = 0;
        cf.negativeSymbol = '-';
        cf.negativeCurrencyFormat = 1;

        // set names
        partner_1.row.partner_ref.text = "P1";
        partner_2.row.partner_ref.text = "P2";
        partner_3.row.partner_ref.text = "P3";
        partner_4.row.partner_ref.text = "P4";
        partner_5.row.partner_ref.text = "P5";

        // set partner parent
        partner_1.row.addEventListener(PartnerEvent.UPDATE,partnerRowUpdateListener);
        partner_2.row.addEventListener(PartnerEvent.UPDATE,partnerRowUpdateListener);
        partner_3.row.addEventListener(PartnerEvent.UPDATE,partnerRowUpdateListener);
        partner_4.row.addEventListener(PartnerEvent.UPDATE,partnerRowUpdateListener);
        partner_5.row.addEventListener(PartnerEvent.UPDATE,partnerRowUpdateListener);

        // init partners
        partners = [partner_1,partner_2,partner_3,partner_4,partner_5];
    }
    private function partnerRowUpdateListener(e:Event) {
        updateSubtotals();
        updateMaxValues();          
        updateLabels();
        updateBarCharts();
    }
    public function update() {
        updateSubtotals();
        updateMaxValues();              
        updateLabels();
        updateBarCharts();
    }
    private function updateMaxValues() {

        var p,partner;

        // loop through partners and add values together
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < partners.length; i++) {
            partner = partners[i].row;
            partner.availableShares = availableShares;
            partner.updateNoEvent();
        }

    }
    private function updateSubtotals() {

        // reset vars
        TPGrossPerc = 0;
        TPGrossAmount = 0;
        RSGrossShareAmount = 0;
        RSGrossAmount = 0;
        RSNetAmount = 0;
        PPGrossPoints = 0;
        PPGrossAmount = 0;
        DGrossPerc = 0;
        DGrossAmount = 0;

        var p,partner;

        // loop through partners and add values together
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < partners.length ; i++) {

            partner = partners[i];

            p = partners[i].row;
            p.FDAmount = FDAmount;
            p.totalInputRS = totalInputRS;
            p.totalInputPP = totalInputPP;
            p.totalInputD = totalInputD;
            p.updateNoEvent();

            if(partner.configEnabled) {

                // add up totals
                TPGrossPerc += p.TPPerc;
                TPGrossAmount += p.TPGrossAmount;
                trace("partner: "+i+" "+p.RSShares);
                RSGrossShareAmount += p.RSShares;

                RSGrossAmount += p.RSGrossAmount;
                RSNetAmount += p.RSGrossMinusTPDrawings;

                PPGrossPoints += p.PPoints;
                PPGrossAmount += p.PPAmount;

                DGrossPerc += p.DPerc;
                DGrossAmount += p.DAmount;

            }

            //TPGrossPerc = Math.max(100,TPGrossPerc);
            //TPGrossAmount = Math.max(totalInput

            //RSNetAmount = Math.min(totalInputRS
            //RSGrossAmount = Math.min(totalInputRS,RSGrossAmount);

        }           
        trace('RSGrossShareAmount: '+RSGrossShareAmount);

        // set available shares
        availableShares = 100 - RSGrossShareAmount;
    }
    private function updateLabels() {

        // set values
        tp_gross_perc_lbl.text = String(TPGrossPerc);
        tp_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(TPGrossAmount,true);

        rs_share_value_lbl.text = cf.format(totalInputRS / 100,true);
        rs_gross_shares_lbl.text = String(RSGrossShareAmount);
        rs_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(RSGrossAmount,true);
        rs_net_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(RSNetAmount,true);

        pp_gross_points_lbl.text = String(PPGrossPoints);
        pp_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(PPGrossAmount,true);

        d_gross_total_lbl.text = String(DGrossPerc);
        d_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(DGrossAmount,true);

    }
    private function updateBarCharts() {

        var bcHeight = 190;
        var bcOnePerc = bcHeight / 100;     
        var p;
        var greatestSalary = 0;
        var maxScale = 0;

        // loop through partners and add values together
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < partners.length ; i++) {
            p = partners[i];
            if(p.row.salary > greatestSalary) {
                greatestSalary = p.row.salary;
            }
        }

        // set max scale
        maxScale = greatestSalary;

        // loop through partners and add values together
        for(i = 0; i < partners.length ; i++) {

            p = partners[i];

            // update label
            if(p.bar_chart_mc != null) {

                p.bar_chart_mc.amount_txt.text = cf.format(p.row.salary,true);

                // get percentages 
                //trace('');
                //trace('p.row.FDAmount: '+p.row.FDAmount);
                //trace('p.row.salary: '+p.row.salary);
                //trace('p.row.FDAmount / p.row.salary: '+(p.row.FDAmount / maxScale) * 100);
                var fdPerc = !((p.row.FDAmount / maxScale) * 100) ? 0 : (p.row.FDAmount / maxScale) * 100;
                var rsPerc = !((p.row.RSGrossMinusTPDrawings / maxScale) * 100) ? 0 : (p.row.RSGrossMinusTPDrawings / maxScale) * 100;
                var tpPerc = !((p.row.TPGrossAmount / maxScale ) * 100) ? 0 : (p.row.TPGrossAmount / maxScale) * 100;
                var ppPerc = !((p.row.PPAmount / maxScale) * 100) ? 0 : (p.row.PPAmount / maxScale) * 100;
                var dPerc = !((p.row.DAmount / maxScale) * 100) ? 0 : (p.row.DAmount / maxScale) * 100;

                //trace('per: '+(fdPerc + rsPerc + tpPerc + ppPerc + dPerc));

                p.bar_chart_mc.fixed_drawings_mc.height = Math.round(bcOnePerc * fdPerc);
                p.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.height = Math.round(bcOnePerc * tpPerc);
                p.bar_chart_mc.responsibility_shares_mc.height = Math.round(bcOnePerc * rsPerc);
                p.bar_chart_mc.performance_points_mc.height = Math.round(bcOnePerc * ppPerc);
                p.bar_chart_mc.discretionary_mc.height = Math.round(bcOnePerc * dPerc);

                p.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.y = p.bar_chart_mc.fixed_drawings_mc.y - p.bar_chart_mc.fixed_drawings_mc.height;
                p.bar_chart_mc.responsibility_shares_mc.y = p.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.y - p.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.height;
                p.bar_chart_mc.performance_points_mc.y = p.bar_chart_mc.responsibility_shares_mc.y - p.bar_chart_mc.responsibility_shares_mc.height;
                p.bar_chart_mc.discretionary_mc.y = p.bar_chart_mc.performance_points_mc.y - p.bar_chart_mc.performance_points_mc.height; 

                //trace('p.bar_chart_mc.fixed_drawings_mc.y: '+p.bar_chart_mc.fixed_drawings_mc.y);
                //trace('pp.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.y: '+p.bar_chart_mc.topup_drawings_mc.y);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Partner class:

```
package com.example.profitdistributiondiagram {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import com.example.profitdistributiondiagram.events.PartnerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TextEvent;
import flash.globalization.CurrencyFormatter;
import flash.globalization.LocaleID;

public class PartnerRow extends MovieClip {

    public var availableShares:Number = 100;
    public var FDAmount:Number = 0;
    public var TPGrossAmount:Number = 0;
    public var TPPerc:Number = 0;

    public var RSGrossAmount:Number = 0;
    public var RSShares:Number = 0;
    public var RSGrossMinusTPDrawings:Number = 0;

    public var PPGrossAmount:Number = 0;
    public var PPoints:Number = 0;
    public var PPAmount:Number = 0;     
    public var PPGrossPoints:Number = 100;

    public var DGrossAmount:Number = 0;
    public var DPerc:Number = 0;
    public var DAmount:Number = 0;

    public var totalInputRS:Number = 0;
    public var totalInputPP:Number = 0;
    public var totalInputD:Number = 0;

    public var salary:Number = 0;

    public var enableControl;
    public var barChart:MovieClip;

    private var cf:CurrencyFormatter;

    public function PartnerRow() {

        // set currency formatter
        cf = new CurrencyFormatter( "en-UK" );
        cf.setCurrency("EUR", "€");
        cf.fractionalDigits = 0;
        cf.negativeSymbol = '-';
        cf.negativeCurrencyFormat = 1;

        // event listeners
        tp_sldr.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderDragHandler);
        rs_sldr.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderDragHandler);
        pp_sldr.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderDragHandler);
        d_sldr.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderDragHandler);

        // update
        update();

    }
    private function sliderDragHandler(event:SliderEvent):void {

        trace('availableShares: '+availableShares);
        trace(' availableShares: '+(availableShares + rs_sldr.value));
        trace('rs_sldr.value: '+rs_sldr.value);

        // check we don't use more shares than available
        if(rs_sldr.value < availableShares + rs_sldr.value) {

            // update shares value if valid
            RSShares = rs_sldr.value;
            //trace("RSShares: "+RSShares);
        }
        trace('max: '+rs_sldr.maximum);
        // update labels
        update();

    }
    public function update() {

        // update but don't dispatch an event
        updateNoEvent();

        // dispatch update event
        this.dispatchEvent(new  Event(PartnerEvent.UPDATE));            
    }
    public function updateNoEvent() {

        // set responsibility shares

        //RSShares = rs_sldr.value;
        RSGrossAmount = (totalInputRS / 100) * RSShares;
        RSGrossMinusTPDrawings = RSGrossAmount - TPGrossAmount;


        // set RS text values
        rs_shares_lbl.text = String(RSShares);
        /*rs_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(RSGrossAmount,true);
        rs_net_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(RSGrossMinusTPDrawings,true);

        // set topup drawings
        TPGrossAmount = (RSGrossAmount / 100) * tp_sldr.value;
        TPPerc = tp_sldr.value;
        tp_perc_lbl.text = String(TPPerc);
        tp_gross_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(TPGrossAmount,true);

        // set performance points
        PPGrossAmount = totalInputPP;
        PPoints = pp_sldr.value;
        PPAmount = (PPGrossAmount / PPGrossPoints) * PPoints;

        // set PP text values
        pp_points_input.text = String(PPoints);
        pp_amount_lbl.text = cf.format(PPAmount,true);

        // set discretionary 
        DGrossAmount = totalInputD;
        DPerc = d_sldr.value;
        DAmount = (DGrossAmount / 100) * DPerc;

        // ser discretionary text values
        d_perc_input.text = String(DPerc);
        d_amount_input.text = cf.format(DAmount,true);
        */
        // set salary
        salary = FDAmount + RSGrossMinusTPDrawings + TPGrossAmount + PPAmount + DAmount;

    }


}
```

}

Comment: So the code is working and you're just looking for general improvements to reduce your misery?

Comment: Agreed can you restate the question.  I don't understand what the problem is you're clearly aware of the maximum property on the slider since you're tracing it so if you want to prevent them from being able to drag to greater than the number of shares just set the maximum to the available shares.